# Placeholder text input on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a little issue at the moment, the text placeholder in the textbox doesn't seem to be showing when viewing on IOS device but works fine on desktop and android...

This is just a simple div with an input field in it.

This is the code I am using :

```
<div id="em_inputs" class="hidden clearfix">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
</div>

@mixin Opacity($value){
  $IEValue: $value*100;
  opacity: $value;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity="+$IEValue+")";
  filter: alpha(opacity=$IEValue);
}

 #em_inputs{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -webkit-border-radius:0; 
            border-radius:0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            top: 127px !important;
            width: 100%;
            input {
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-appearance: none;                   
                -webkit-border-radius:0; 
                border-radius:0;
                border: none;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 12px 5px 11px 10px;
                color: $text-white;
                background: url("../img/bg_input.png") repeat 0 0;
                margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                @include Opacity(0);
                position: relative;
                top: -10px;
                height: 3px;
                overflow: hidden;
                &:focus{
                    border: 2px solid $text-white;
                }
            }
```

I am also using this code that makes the placeholder text white color in case a browser uses special rules.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: white;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: white;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: white;  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar { 
     display: none; 
}
```

Does someone have any idea what I going on ? I am not only interested in getting the code fixed but also know if someone experienced the same issues with IOS placeholders in general being a bit picky ?

Could it be because of the background image too ?

Comment: It's really hard to make sense of such a small part of something bigger. The more context you can provide the better. Also a jsfiddle demo would help us understand and test the problem. You are also using SASS and including the function `Opacity` - what does that do? Please help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answers.

The text of the placeholder appears when changing the orientation of the device. That is changing the float.

What I do is just before the page fully loads I do a reset of the float and it works.

This is the source that helped me out.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201301/the_mysterious_webkit_placeholder_overflow_bug/